# Replace placeholder in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my JSP site I want to copy some html elements and rename their attributes to generate a dynamic form. Currently my javascript code looks like this:

```
function getTemplateHtml(templateType)
{
    <%-- Get current number of elements. --%>
    var len = $('.form-group').length;
    <%-- Clone the correct template. --%>
    var $html = $(".template-"+templateType).clone();
    <%-- Replace placeholders. --%>
    $html.find('[id="PLACEHOLDER.Type"]')[0].id="filters" + len + ".Type";
    $html.find('[name="PLACEHOLDER.Type"]')[0].name="filters[" + len + "].Type";
    $html.find('[id="PLACEHOLDER.Value"]')[0].id="filters" + len + ".Value";
    $html.find('[name="PLACEHOLDER.Value"]')[0].name="filters[" + len + "].Value";
    ...
    return $html.html();    
}
```

Since there are 20 attributes, the code is very long and hard to maintain. Is there a way to call something like `.replace('PLACEHOLDER', 'filters' + len)` on the entire `$hmtl` element?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying there are 20 different things that may be where you have PLACEHOLDER above?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: With 20 I mean Type, Value etc.. I currently have 20 lines with `.find`. However, in each line only the `PLACEHOLDER`is replaced. Thus, it could be replaced by a single line always replacing `PLACEHOLDER` with a value independent of the current attribute.

Comment: Likely no need to even have `id` on those elements and only need class. Also suspect that using classes would make this all a lot simpler both in targeting the elements as well as updating the attributes. Show an html sample

Comment: @Thanthla - Ah, okay, I've updated my answer to do that instead (it's very similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an [`attribute starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [`attr(attributeName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) you could probably do something generic like:

```
$html.find('[name^="PLACEHOLDER"]').attr('name', function(i, existingName){
     return existingName.replace('PLACEHOLDER', 'filters[' + len +']');
});
```

I would get rid of the `id` completely and use class instead. Managing dynamic id's is almost always more trouble than it is worth

Comment: I have choosen this solution, altghough @T.J. Crowder also had a nice approach. However, this solution was for me easier to understand/maintain in the future. I copied the code for id.

Comment: I use the spring form syntax `<form:input path="dummy.Type" ...>` which is replaced by ìd` and `name` autonmatically.

Comment: Am guessing the id is on same element and if so could change the id inside the same callback in by answer. Just do `this.id = this.id.replace(...` beffore the `return`

Comment: Note if you remove any of the rows you will end up with duplicate names unless you keep track of previous count

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you could have 20 different attributes where you have `Type` and `Value` in your question, yes, you can readily do that work in a loop:

```
["id", "name"].forEach(function(prop) {
    $html.find('[' + prop + '*=PLACEHOLDER]').attr(prop, function() {
        var match = /PLACEHOLDER\.([A-Z]+)/i.exec(this[prop]);
        if (match) {
            this[prop] = "filters" + len + "." + match[1];
        }
    });
});
```

That looks for all elements with `PLACEHOLDER` in their `id` or `name` and updates the `id` or `name` with the replacement, taking the attribute name ("Type" or "Value", etc.) from the `id` or `name`.

Live Example:

```js
var len = 27;
var $html = $("#template").clone();
["id", "name"].forEach(function(prop) {
    $html.find('[' + prop + '*=PLACEHOLDER]').attr(prop, function() {
        var match = /PLACEHOLDER\.([A-Z]+)/i.exec(this[prop]);
        if (match) {
            this[prop] = "filters" + len + "." + match[1];
        }
    });
});
console.log($html.html());
```

```html
<div id="template">
<input id="PLACEHOLDER.Type">
<input name="PLACEHOLDER.Type">
<input id="PLACEHOLDER.Value">
<input name="PLACEHOLDER.Value">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's simpler if we can assume the `id` and `name` are on the same element:

```
$html.find('[id*=PLACEHOLDER]').attr("id", function() {
    var match = /PLACEHOLDER\.([A-Z]+)/i.exec(this.id);
    if (match) {
        this.id = this.name = "filters" + len + "." + match[1];
    }
});
```

That looks for all elements with `PLACEHOLDER` in their `id` or `name` and updates the `id` or `name` with the replacement, taking the attribute name ("Type" or "Value", etc.) from the `id` or `name`.

Live Example:

```js
var len = 27;
var $html = $("#template").clone();
$html.find('[id*=PLACEHOLDER]').attr("id", function() {
    var match = /PLACEHOLDER\.([A-Z]+)/i.exec(this.id);
    if (match) {
        this.id = this.name = "filters" + len + "." + match[1];
    }
});
console.log($html.html());
```

```html
<div id="template">
<input id="PLACEHOLDER.Type">
<input name="PLACEHOLDER.Type">
<input id="PLACEHOLDER.Value">
<input name="PLACEHOLDER.Value">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So, I still need the list of attributes? If I add an attribute to the html, I also have to update the list. Is there no generic way to replace "all" PLACEHOLDERS independent of the attibutname? The for-loop, however, makes the code much cleaner.

Comment: @Thanthla - Ah, yes, that is possible. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Thanthla - Updated to do that.

Comment: Also guessing the id and name are actually on same element

Comment: @Thanthla - Can I assume the `id` and `name` are the same on the same element? That's often how these things are, but...

Comment: Yes, they are on the same. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @Thanthla - Updated again.